# Flutter scroll element by element

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want when someone scroll down to jump to the next element and when they scroll up to go to the previous element

Here is an example, but I need to implement it without the two buttons :
[image: example]

Comment: We're not here to solve your homework assignments. Use this site to share problems with code you have actually written and solutions you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: BTW In Flutter scrolling behavior is defined by the ScrollPhysics which may be set by ScrollBehavior https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollBehavior-class.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ber above in the comments that Stack overflow is not for HW.

Anyway, you need to use a ScrollController for this.
and you need to count the pixel count for each ListTile.

say each ListTile is about 50px (tall or height), then, you need to jump either 50px up or down on the onClick of those buttons repectively.

```
ScrollController _controller;

@override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }
```

and button:

```
  _handleOnClickForMoveUpButton() {
    _controller.jumpTo(pixelsToMove);
  }
```

For further assistance, you can have a look at this medium article:
[link to article](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac)